# Jquery jsonp response error - Callback was not called

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to get some information from a different domain, the domain allows only jsonp call - others get rejected. How can I get the content instead of execution? Because I get an error in response. I don't need to execute it, I just need it in my script. In any format (the response is json but js doesn't understand it).
I can't affect on that domain so it's impossible to change something on that side.
Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + '?callback=?',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: {key: key},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + '; ' + error);
    }
});

window.jsonpCallback = function(response) {
    console.log('callback success');
};
```

Comment: what is the response from the server

Answer (score 16):

There are a few issues with your `$.ajax` call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + '?callback=?',
    // this is not needed for JSONP.  What this does, is force a local
    // AJAX call to accessed as if it were cross domain
    crossDomain: true,
    // JSONP can only be GET
    type: "POST",
    data: {key: key},
    // contentType is for the request body, it is incorrect here
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    // This does not work with JSONP, nor should you be using it anyway.
    // It will lock up the browser
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    // This changes the parameter that jQuery will add to the URL
    jsonp: 'callback',
    // This overrides the callback value that jQuery will add to the URL
    // useful to help with caching
    // or if the URL has a hard-coded callback (you need to set jsonp: false)
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + '; ' + error);
    }
});
```

You should be calling your url like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {key: key},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('callback success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + '; ' + error);
    }
});
```

JSONP is *not* JSON.  JSONP is actually just adding a script tag to your `<head>`.  The response needs to be a JavaScript file containing a function call with the JSON data as a parameter.

JSONP is something the server needs to support.  If the server doesn't respond correctly, you can't use JSONP.

Please read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "https://status.github.com/api/status.json?callback=apiStatus";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'apiStatus',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('callback success: ', response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + '; ' + error);
    }
});
```

Try this code.

Also try calling this [url](https://status.github.com/api/status.json?callback=apiStatus) directly in ur browser and see what it exactly returns, by this way You can understand better what actually happens :).

Comment: This answer solves his problem, But makes the problem solution very abstract and doesn't help others apply this to their situations.

Answer (score 1):

The `jsonpCallback` parameter is used for specifying the name of the function in the JSONP response, not the name of the function in your code. You can likely remove this; jQuery will handle this automatically on your behalf.

Instead, you're looking for the `success` parameter (to retrieve the response data). For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: {key: key},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('callback success');
        console.log(data);
    }
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + '; ' + error);
    }
});
```

You can also likely remove the other JSONP-releated parameters, which were set to jQuery defaults. See [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information.

Comment: There still some more issues here.  JSONP cannot be POST.  The `contentType` is for the *request*, not response (remove it).  `async:false` is usually bad idea, and doesn't work with JSONP.