# API Call: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am running an ajax call to get some Data from an API. The call itself works fine, I get 200 (OK) as a response. Also I can See the JSON Data in my Dev Tools. But in the end the alert is "error" and the I have a *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"* in my Console.

What going wrong there?

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'my url',
                type:'GET',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

                // headers: {
                //     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('uberall:cat-aspirin-window-cake')
                // },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ":" + pw));
                },

                success: function(text) { alert('success'); },
                error: function (text) { alert('error'); },
                complete: function(text) { alert('complete'); }
            });
```

Comment: Did you check request content with tools like Advanced Rest API, Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsonp , you should have a callback method implemented, it seems you are missing it.

You may first try to print the error by replacing the following function to error field, see if it is missing the jsonpCallback or other error

```
error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log("jqXHR",jqXHR);
    console.log("textStatus",textStatus);
    console.log("errorThrown",errorThrown);
}
```

If it is jsonp you should check server side see what should be the callback, but you do not know , you may try add as many server set this as default

Note: this is not a good pratice

```
jsonp: 'callback'
```

and also ref to [JSONP NOT CALL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170211/4453627)

Comment: I receive this error:
 
 errorThrown Error: jQuery321044028430193306467_1503491162480 was not called
    at Function.error (master.js:273)
    at s.converters.script json (master.js:9702)
    at ajaxConvert (master.js:8754)
    at done (master.js:9222)
    at HTMLScriptElement.callback (master.js:9639)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (master.js:5206)
    at HTMLScriptElement.elemData.handle (master.js:5014)

    so I guess you are right with the callback, but how do I do that?

Comment: jqXHR {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
textStatus parsererror

Comment: yes, this error mean your jsonpCallback is not called, please check your data type see if it is JSON or JSONP as this 2 are different. if it is JSONP 
please check server side see what method should be implemented.

Comment: For me the Data type looks like JSON:{"APPLE_MAPS":"Apple Maps","AUDI":"Audi","BMW":"BMW","FACEBOOK":"Facebook"} but when I exchange Datatype with "json" instead of "jsonp" I receive a 401

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
listings:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load mywebsite.com/en/website/directoryNames?_=1503493325760. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mywebsite.dev' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: while you are using json type, the dataType should be json instead of jsonp. The No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem can only solve via the server or if you really cant do that, there are 2 possible way people using suggested to do the trick.
1. using php to add header for certain domain response received
2. using .Net or other way wrap the content and get it in the same domain

Comment: Thank you a lot. In my case php won't do it, because I need only snippets of the API after user interaction. I dont want to load all the data in advance... by .NET do you mean that? : https://dotnetthoughts.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: yes, using the cross domain feature to wrap the contents and deploy the mvc or asp to same domain to obtain the data.